# How to work with 2 Spinners in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Why is this code not working? is there any problem with switch case?
I have 2 spinners (of branch and semester). When a branch is selected it must show a Toast of selected branch and same with the semester.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener{

Spinner branch, semester;
Button go;
TextView branchText, semText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    branch = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    semester = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Branch, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    branch.setAdapter(adapter);
    branch.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Semester, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    semester.setAdapter(adapter1);
    semester.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    go.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.spinner1:
        branchText = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this, branchText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.spinner2:
        semText = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this, semText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the id of selected item by "AdapterView parent" not "View view".

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

switch (parent.getId()){

case R.id.spinner1:
    branchText = (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this, branchText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;

case R.id.spinner2:
    semText = (TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this, semText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  `Toast.makeText(this, branchText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` to `Toast.makeText(this, branchText.getText().tostring(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
change all `branchText.getText()` to `branchText.getText().tostring()`

Comment: actually there is no error
app is working but toast does not display.

Answer (score 0):

Reference branch array and use position to retrieve branch text:

```
String[] branchArr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Branch);

case R.id.spinner1:
    Toast.makeText(this, branchArr[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
```